Joint distribution of continuous random variable and discrete random variable
For my data analysis course I was given the exercise that you can see in the images. I have also provided my solution. I'm really not certain whether my solution is correct, because i have never tried to find the joint distribution of a discrete and continuous random variable. I worry that I've misinterpreted the formula that I used to find the joint distribution. What are your opinions? Thank you in advance.part1part2

If $Z$ has a density and $W$ is Bernoulli, then there is no density $f_{Z,W}(z,w)$ for $(Z,W)$

Please don't link to external resources, but provide all information pertinent to the question here.
